# UIWebBroswerView has gap from top of UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, ios9, ios9.2

I have a `UIWebView` which is taking up a whole view in my ViewController, which you can see here:

[image: WebView]

What I don't understand, is when I run my app, the contents of my `UIWebView` does not fill up the whole screen, you can see this here, where I first show the extent of the `UIWebView` (it is indeed taking up the whole screen):

[image: WebView]

And then here, where I show the extend of the `UIWebBrowserView` (which seems to have a gap from the top of the `UIWebView`).

[image: WebView]

Does anyone know why the `UIWebBrowserView` has a gap from the top of the `UIWebView`?

Comment: set none to top bar as none is your storyboard/xib or direct hidden navigation bar using programming.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I think this happens because of UIViewController's ScrollView Inset Property. Default value for `adjustScrollViewInset` is `True`.

Select **ViewController** and go to **Attribute Inspector** Tab.
Uncheck `Adjust Scroll View Insets` option.

[image]

Comment: Please  mark answer as accepted, if it solves your issue.

Comment: Works great, thanks!